Samuel French Format Drama Template?
I am looking for an example of a latex template using one of the playwriting packages, such as dramatist, which allows me to write plays, hopefully in the Samuel French format.  Thank you.

Please clarify your question wrt typesetting, i.e.: please EDIT it. // Examples you can find in form of MWEs when clicking on your two tags. // Available templates for drama are here: https://ctan.org/topic/drama-script . // Who is S.F.? // The SF-format you can find online seem to be close to screenplay; see https://www.dramatistsguild.com/sites/default/files/2020-01/General-SFI-Formatting-Guidelines-Complete.pdf or https://static1.squarespace.com/static/52f9468ce4b0a6dd2f9f0607/t/606a0b885e4fca448604045b/1617562504281/%20Playwriting+Formatting+Guidelines.pdf . // Thank you

What edits should I implement, my friend?  PNAS (Proceedings of National Academy of Science), Science, and Nature all have their particular styles to format scientific papers.  For example, the PNAS LaTeX template is found here https://www.pnas.org/author-center/submitting-your-manuscript.  Analogously, I am looking for a template for the Samuel French playwriting style.
You have linked the style guide, but I want an actual template.  I have already looked at the ctan.org link and the tags, and I believe that they do not contain useful templates.
How can I make this question clearer?

So it doesn't exist or isn't provided by whoever shall be your recipient. // Allow me to exaggerate to make it more evident: At the moment you more post an order, either to search or to develop. That's not how this place works. E.g. even here S.F. seems to be unknown: https://writing.stackexchange.com/ . // Now, this is a very code oriented community. If you'd EDIT your Q providing a) a screenshot of 1 or 2 pages as they should look like, AND b) your own code attempts with the "best" package, AND c) indicate where you failed ... you'd had all vetrans here on your side. (Focus on 1 problem only
